# forge viewer rendering is too slow on ec2 server. How can I speed up the rendering speed?

Tags: autodesk-forge

We deployed forge viewer as a trial version on AWS EC2 for testing. However, the viewer operates quickly locally, but when we upload it to the server and test its operation, it is too slow. Can you tell me what the reason is?

Comment: When you said slow, did you mean by loading the model in APS Viewer? you could share the browser console log and network log with us (please send to that private ticket #18755 you created by aps.help@autodesk.com) . We could try to take a look at what might be the cause. In addition, have you tested with APS tutorial ? https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/